# Accessible table with Vertical and Horizontal Headers

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I'm working on a table that looks similar to my example below where X's in cells denote certain criteria based on the intersection of the respective horizontal/vertical headings.

For instance, in this situation an orange would have the qualities of "sweet" and "sour" but not salty or bitter.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Sweet</th>
        <th scope="col">Sour</th>
        <th scope="col">Salty</th>
        <th scope="col">Bitter</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Apple</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Orange</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What would be the appropriate way to mark this up so that it is semantic and accessible? It seems as if cells should contain something more extensive than just an "X" to be meaningful, even if visually it just shows an "X".

Also, should the visibly empty cells actually contain some visually hidden text that states that said cell is not applicable?

Comment: I'd say use a tick, but your question really does come down to personal preference, which makes it [**too broad**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Is using a single mark like a tick or bullet useful to users who use screen readers or other assistive technologies in this case?

Comment: A tick is arguably more 'useful' than a cross, as it has positive connotations, and your fruits would possess those qualities. As I say, your question is far too broad, as it depends entirely on both personal opinion and what you *want* the output to be. Sure, you could use a tick. You could also use background colours or audio. But those wouldn't work for the colorblind or deaf. Work out your market, and work out which approach is *least* likely to cause issue. Considering you don't specify your *exact* intent for your table, it's impossible for us to know which approach would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that "Yes" and "No" are great indicators, but do require some context (i.e scrolling to the heading of the table)

Having the text "sweet" "sour" "salty" or "bitter" is also an evident choice that would perfectly fit.

Everybody hates ticks in a consecutive table columns which do require a lot of attention.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Apple</th>
        <td>Sweet</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Orange</th>
        <td>Sweet</td>
        <td>Sour</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```